# How to set --max-old-space-size via npm link command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, v8

Is there a way to set --max-old-space-size via npm link?

I know it can be set via the node command like node --max-old-space-size=, however i'm trying to do the same via npm link command, is that possible? please advise.

Comment: [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) has nothing whatsoever to do with running `node`? What are you trying to do, what is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: i have a CLI tool created using node which process very large files, i create a symlink for it via npm link command and then run the cli via the symlink name. i need to set the --max_old_space_size to a larger value like 16GB so i can run the CLI without memory issues via the symlink name

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issues is discussed here:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12238

**Best way to set --max-old-space-size when running npm?**

The most straight forward approach I see is:

> use aliasing to pass options to node for npm. Here is my .bashrc:
>
> alias npm='node --max_old_space_size=8000 /usr/bin/npm'

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12238#issuecomment-257018646